# Как правильно скомпилировать программу на python, использующую PyQt5, при помощи pyinstaller?

Tags: python, компиляция, python-3.5, exe, pyinstaller

Пытался собрать при помощи pyinstaller следующую программу на PyQt5:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QLabel()
w.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
w.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
w.setText("Draw text...")
w.setFont(QFont("Times", 25, QFont.Normal))
# w.move(x, y) or center
w.adjustSize()  # update w.rect() now
w.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - w.rect().center())
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вроде все собирается, но при попытке открыть собранный файл вижу следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сталкивался ли кто-то с чем-то похожим? Как победили?

**Update:** Если положить собранный экзешник в папку `C:\Users\tuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32`, т.е в одну папку с файлом `qt.conf`, в котором прописаны пути к pyqt, то все работает нормально. Но ведь тогда необходимо наличие pyqt у юзера, т.е. это не самостоятельный исполняемый файл?

Comment: @jfs, сейчас попробую, спасибо. Вся информация не подходила по ограничениям (слишком много символов).

Answer (score 1):

Для простого кода в вопросе работает pypi версия pyinstaller:

```
$ pyinstaller --version
3.3.1
```

Поддержка для pyqt5 была [обновлена в Апреле 2018](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/3439). Если ещё не выпущена версия с этим патчем, то можно установить версию прямо из develop ветки на github:

```
$ py -mpip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip#egg=pyinstaller
$ pyinstaller --version                         
3.4.dev0+d4cc9fe33
```

Сборка с помощью команды:

```
$ pyinstaller --onefile --windowed pyqt5-draw-text-in-desktop-center.py
...
4464 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
4554 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
4652 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
4653 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
4709 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
...
```

завершилась успешно—исполняемый файл создан и при запуске:

```
$ dist/pyqt5-draw-text-in-desktop-center
```

команда показывает надпись в центре экрана как и ожидалось.

Comment: Установил последнюю версию, ввел в командной строке `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed test_pyqt5.py --paths C:\Users\tuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins`, в ответ получаю: `Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
Paths checked: C:/Qt/5.6.0/plugins`, хотя путь вроде прописал.

Comment: @tuta: убедитесь, что чистая текущая директория (ничего кроме `yqt5-draw-text-in-desktop-center.py`). Затем выполните команду как она записана в ответе. Если произойдёт какая-то ошибка, то *обновите вопрос* указав точные команды и конкретную ошибку (если вывод большой, то по своему усмотрению сократите (и ссылку на полный вывод добавьте на всякий случай)). Убедитесь, что версии ПО видны в выводе.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, собрать в единый файл не получилось. Если при сборке не писать `--onefile`, то нужно переместить `qwindows.dll` из `dist\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll` в `dist\platforms\qwindows.dll`. Еще об этой ошибке можно почитать [здесь](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2857).

**Update:** снес `pyqt5`, поставил заново через `pip`. Через него же поставил `pyqt5-tools` и `sip`. Все нормально собирается в один файл.

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает сборка с `--onefile`?

Comment: @a6461, так проблема возникает как раз при сборке с `--onefile` (у меня). Без него тоже не работает, но если переместить `dll` то все будет хорошо.