# Сборка приложения

Tags: pyqt5

Что нужно сделать для сборки приложения PyQt5 в .exe?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно скомпилировать программу на python, использующую PyQt5, при помощи pyinstaller?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834055/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-pyqt5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8)

Comment: набрать в google:  https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20PyQt5%20%D0%B2%20.exe?

Comment: pyinstaller........

Answer (score 0):

Модуль pyinstaller. pip install pyinstaller

pyinstaller имяфайла